# A type declaration is implicitly a static member

Tags: c#

Someone I know just asked me to explain this statement [from the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx) and I was dumbfounded.

> A constant or type declaration is implicitly a static member.

That phrase "or type declaration is implicitly a static member," just doesn't make sense to me.

What does that mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It makes sense to me that a `type declaration is implicitly a static member`.
Because if you have class:

```
class Foo
{
   public class Bar
  {
  }
}
```

You **cannot** access the class `Bar` by:

```
Foo f = new Foo();
Bar b =new f.Bar();
```

(I am not even sure how to write it in order for it to make sense).
If you want to access `Bar` class, you will need to do as follows:

```
Bar b = new Foo.Bar()
```

**You access it via the class rather than an instance. of an object**
Hence, `Bar` is a static member of `Foo`.

Comment: @TGH It is, read MSDN, type declaration is implicitly static member. And we access nested class as we access static member. Infact class is static member of Namespace and that is low level .net framework implementation.

Comment: @AkashKava: Two things: (1) Could you please point me to an authoritative source like the part in the CLR documentation that states that type declarations are implemented as static members? Because though it makes sense to naturally assume that, it is better to look for documentation before making the assumption. (2) Even if that were true, that statement would make no sense appearing in the C# language documentation.

Comment: The reason this appears in Language spec # because it is different from java. In this answer the first method of accessing nested class through instance of class is possible and nested class can not be instantiated without parent instance. In java every nested class keeps reference of parent instance as closure. Where else in C# nested class can be created without parent instance. This is big design decision as it changes the way programmers use it. And it is not .net framework but it is C# that imposes this design.  You can create your own language and support java kind of nested classes.

Comment: Thanks, Akash. What you're saying does make sense. Is there some place I can read more about it?

Answer (score 2):

In the context of this article, I believe they are defining types to simply be the definitions of inner-`struct`s, inner-`class`es, and `enum`s -- which can always be referenced in a static context as a type.

Comment: Thank you. I suspected that, too. Let's see if someone from within the C# team can offer an insight.

Comment: Even class is static member of Namespace. The implementation differs from java because in Java nested classes are not static members.

Answer (score 2):

It means that when you define a class like this,

```
 public class Message
    {

        const int i = 10;

        enum NewType{ typeval, typevale2 }


    }
```

Here both are implicitly static members.

Comment: Thank you, Rajesh. That makes sense and I was inclined to naturally assume that as the meaning. Could you point me to some documentation that explicitly states that?

Answer (score 0):

Const is implicitly static, but it differs from a plain static field in that it can't change during the execution of your program. It's still static though..

Comment: And what about type? You have answered only half the question.

Answer (score 0):

**type declaration**

> A type-declaration is a class-declaration (Section 10.1), a struct-declaration (Section 11.1), an interface-declaration (Section 13.1), an enum-declaration (Section 14.1), or a delegate-declaration (Section 15.1).

from *[Type declarations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664768%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)* MSDN Doc

**static members**

> When a field, method, property, event, operator, or constructor declaration includes a static modifier, it declares a static member. In addition, a constant or type declaration implicitly declares a static member. Static members have the following characteristics:
>
> - When a static member M is referenced in a member-access (Section 7.5.4) of the form E.M,E must denote a type containing M. It is a compile-time error for E to denote an instance.
> - A static field identifies exactly one storage location. No matter how many instances of a class are created, there is only ever one copy of a static field.
> - A static function member (method, property, event, operator, or constructor) does not operate on a specific instance, and it is a compile-time error to refer to this in such a function member.

from *[Static and instance members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645629(v=vs.71).aspx)* MSDN Doc

So that means `Constants` and all kind of `Type declaration` are static without add keyword `static`.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, but that just states what the question does without explaining anything. All of it explains what static members are. None of it, except one sentence, is relevant to the question I asked. And that statement is exactly the statement I am curious to know the meaning of.